Identify Pattern in Column and Copy Only Unique Pattern or Range of Unique Pattern to Another Column
Column A: TaskID, Column B: StaffUserID, Column C: WeekNumber, Column D: DayofWeek, Column E: Output of script.
I have a google sheet with over 7000 rows of data. Each TaskID and StaffUserID are combined correlating with WeekNumber: 1 through 12 and DayofWeek (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday). Sequence is defined as with each TaskID and StaffUserID - with having the same WeekNumber - ie: WeekNumber: 1, DayofWeek row by row sequence could be: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.
Same WeekNumber 2: DayofWeek Sequence could be: Monday, Wednesday, Friday. Same WeekNumber 3: DayofWeek sequence could be: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.
The goal is to eliminate as much data from the google sheet as possible. This can be done by finding a DayofWeek sequence (or pattern)  within the WeekNumber 1 through 12 for each TaskID and StaffUserID combination. Columns A, B, C, D are provided. Column E is the script actual and expected output to find unique DayofWeek sequence for each WeekNumbers for each Unique TaskID and StaffUserID and output the common pattern row by row.
So if Unique TaskID and StaffUserID combination have WeekNumber 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 with the same DayofWeek sequence and 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 have the same DayofWeek sequence, then this data should be removed to only have WeekNumber 1 and 2 DayofWeek sequences output.
The issue I am running into is that my script finds the "unique" TaskID and StaffUserID, DayofWeek per row. However, if this is found in WeekNumber 2 as well, but not the same sequence as WeekNumber 1, then it doesn't copy it to column E because technically it already "found" the unique combination. I need to copy the unique DayofWeek sequences for WeekNumber 1 through 12 for each unique TaskID and StaffUserID. AND ALSO if there is the same sequence in the middle of unique sequences, I need all sequences from the first Unique sequence to the last unique sequence to be copied to column E row by row and correlating where each DayofWeek is found. This shortens a 7000 row data file to like 800 rows or something. Below are some examples:
Example:




A
B
C
D
E




1
TaskID
StaffUserID
WeekNumber
DayofWeek
Correct Script Output


2
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Monday
Monday


3
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Tuesday
Tuesday


4
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Wednesday
Wednesday


5
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Thursday
Thursday


6
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Friday
Friday


7
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Monday
Monday


8
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Tuesday
Tuesday


9
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Wednesday
Wednesday


10
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Thursday
Thursday


11
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Friday
Friday


12
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
3
Monday



13
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
3
Tuesday



14
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
3
Wednesday



15
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
3
Thursday



16
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
3
Friday



17
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
4
Monday



18
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
4
Tuesday



19
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
4
Wednesday



20
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
4
Thursday



21
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
4
Friday




Example below where WeekNumber 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6 are all "unique DayofWeek" per TaskID and StaffUserID combination. However, WeekNumber 5 TaskID and StaffUserID combo is found in WeekNumber 2 so technically it's not "unique", but I still need the data to be filled in for 1st WeekNumber that has a unique common pattern and the last WeekNumber with a unique common pattern.
Script output in column E:




A
B
C
D
E




1
TaskID
StaffUserID
WeekNumber
DayofWeek
Actual Incorrect Script Output


2
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Monday
Monday


3
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Tuesday
Tuesday


4
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Wednesday
Wednesday


5
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Thursday
Thursday


6
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Friday
Friday


7
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Monday
Monday


8
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Tuesday
Tuesday


9
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Wednesday
Wednesday


10
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Thursday
Thursday


11
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Friday
Friday


12
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Monday
Monday


13
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Tuesday
Tuesday


14
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Wednesday
Wednesday


15
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Thursday
Thursday


16
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Friday
Friday


17
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Monday
Monday


18
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Tuesday
Tuesday


19
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Wednesday
Wednesday


20
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Thursday
Thursday


21
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Friday
Friday


22
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Monday



23
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Tuesday



24
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Wednesday



25
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Thursday



26
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Friday



27
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Monday
Monday


28
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Tuesday
Tuesday


29
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Wednesday
Wednesday


30
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Thursday
Thursday


31
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Friday
Friday



I would need WeekNumber 5 to be filled out with the DayofWeek as well even if it wasn't unique because any DayofWeek from the first unique to the last unique should be filled.
Expected Output:




A
B
C
D
E




1
TaskID
StaffUserID
WeekNumber
DayofWeek
Expected Script Output


2
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Monday
Monday


3
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Tuesday
Tuesday


4
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Wednesday
Wednesday


5
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Thursday
Thursday


6
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Friday
Friday


7
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Monday
Monday


8
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Tuesday
Tuesday


9
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Wednesday
Wednesday


10
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Thursday
Thursday


11
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
2
Friday
Friday


12
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Monday
Monday


13
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Tuesday
Tuesday


14
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Wednesday
Wednesday


15
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Thursday
Thursday


16
CMC 1L - 0900 - 1730
Test
3
Friday
Friday


17
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Monday
Monday


18
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Tuesday
Tuesday


19
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Wednesday
Wednesday


20
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Thursday
Thursday


21
CMC 1E - 0700 - 1530
Test
4
Friday
Friday


22
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Monday
Monday


23
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Tuesday
Tuesday


24
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Wednesday
Wednesday


25
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Thursday
Thursday


26
CMC 2M - 0800 - 1630
Test
5
Friday
Friday


27
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Monday
Monday


28
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Tuesday
Tuesday


29
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Wednesday
Wednesday


30
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Thursday
Thursday


31
CMC 2L - 0930 - 1800
Test
6
Friday
Friday



Another example would be that although the unique combination of TaskId and StaffID with DayofWeek was found. It needs to still fill out WeekNumber 2 on column E because the row sequence is still different in WeekNumber 2. However, it doesn't place anything for the rows because it already found the unique combination in WeekNumber 1 in rows 2,3, & 4.




A
B
C
D
E




1
TaskID
StaffUserID
WeekNumber
DayofWeek
Actual Incorrect Script Output


2
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Monday
Monday


3
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Tuesday
Tuesday


4
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Wednesday
Wednesday


5
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Thursday
Thursday


6
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Friday
Friday


7
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
2
Monday



8
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
2
Tuesday



9
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
2
Wednesday




Expected output:




A
B
C
D
E




1
TaskID
StaffUserID
WeekNumber
DayofWeek
Expected Script Output


2
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Monday
Monday


3
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Tuesday
Tuesday


4
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Wednesday
Wednesday


5
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Thursday
Thursday


6
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
1
Friday
Friday


7
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
2
Monday
Monday


8
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
2
Tuesday
Tuesday


9
CMC 2E - 0730 - 1600
Test
2
Wednesday
Wednesday



When I tried to implement a WeekNumber variable, it just saw each WeekNumber DayofWeek sequences as unique. But below is my script without a WeekNumber variable.
function copyCommonDayOfWeekPattern() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:D" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // Dictionary to store common DayOfWeek patterns for each TaskID and StaffUserID combination
  var commonPatterns = {};
  var startingRows = {}; // Dictionary to store starting row for each TaskID-StaffUserID combination
  
  // Iterate through the data to find common patterns and starting rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var taskID = data[i][0]; // TaskID is in the first column
    var staffUserID = data[i][1]; // StaffUserID is in the second column
    var dayOfWeek = data[i][3]; // DayOfWeek is in the fourth column
    
    var key = taskID + '-' + staffUserID;
    if (!commonPatterns[key]) {
      commonPatterns[key] = [];
      startingRows[key] = i + 2; // Starting row for this TaskID-StaffUserID combination
    }
    
    if (commonPatterns[key].indexOf(dayOfWeek) === -1) {
      commonPatterns[key].push(dayOfWeek);
    }
  }
  
  // Paste the common patterns to column E
  for (var key in commonPatterns) {
    var patterns = commonPatterns[key];
    var startingRow = startingRows[key];
    for (var j = 0; j < patterns.length; j++) {
      sheet.getRange(startingRow + j, 5).setValue(patterns[j]); // Paste to column E
    }
  }
}


Hi @Blindspots Another example:
thanks for editing the post to make it much more presentable! The desired output would have WeekNumber 5 filled in as well, even if it wasn't unique because WeekNumber 6 is unique. I edited the post to add examples and expected output :)

Hi @Blindspots
Columns: A, B, C, D is provided data.
This data could be 7000 or more rows with WeekNumber being 1 through 12.
The end goal is to cut down the data so it only shows the unique DayofWeek pattern found for each unique TaskID and StaffUserID. If WeekNumber 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 have the same "DayofWeek" row sequence.. and if WeekNumber 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 have the same "DayofWeek" row sequence, per unique TaskID and StaffUserID combo, ideally - I want the script to find this and cut to: WeekNumber 1, WeekNumber 2
Column: E, is the script output attempting to find unique pattern.

@Blindspots like in the first example WeekNumber 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6 have a unique TaskID and StaffUserID combination. However, WeekNumber 5 isn't being placed because the TaskID and StaffUserID found these days in WeekNumber 2 so it didn't place, even though I want it to fill for the unique combination from the first WeekNumber found and last WeekNumber found.
Second Example:
Script found WeekNumber 1 with DayofWeek Mon-Friday being unique. So the issue is that WeekNumber 2 has the same DayofWeek, but a different sequence. So  I want the script to although find unique combo & also sequence.

Hi @Blindspots I have updated the post to include the details.
DayofWeek sequence according to each WeekNumber is on each corresponding row. So row by row: WeekNumber 1: DayofWeek: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.
WeekNumber 2: DayofWeek: Tuesday, Thursday. WeekNumber 3: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday. WeekNumber 4: Tuesday, Thursday.
Script should find that WeekNumber 1 and WeekNumber 3 have the same DayofWeek sequence per unique TaskID and StaffUserID and cut it to WeekNumber 1 DayofWeek: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.
Same for WeekNumber 2 and WeekNumber 4.

Hi @Blindspots this is something that will need to be done multiple times for many different clients with large sets of data so I figured running a script will be easier and I don't know how I would do it in a formula. In this 7000 rows, there are roughly 125 unique staff members. So it will resolve an insane amount of manual work to remove the unnecessary data. Instead of having 12 WeekNumbers per unique staff member, it could cut it down to 2 WeekNumbers with correlating DayofWeek. Some would be outliers like having 6 WeekNumbers worth of DayofWeek, but I want the script to find that

@Blindspots in an effort to make this post smaller, I didn't include the data up to WeekNumber 12 for the examples. The DayofWeek would just be repeating per WeekNumber.

Thanks @Blindspots. I commented on the sheet hopefully it clarifies.
My script currently performs like Result 1, Result 2, and Result 3a. Trying to figure out how I can get 3b and 4b included.

Hi @Blindspots, I added to the excel sheet yesterday.
I also have figured the issue out for the most part. I am just now trying to sort the data correctly. It appears that the duplicate sequence is identified with the unique sequence together. So when the data is copied over it outputs the duplicate sequence in such.

@Blindspots
For example:
Needing all WeekNumbers for TaskID & StaffUserID before the last unique WeekNumber per group: TaskID&StaffUserID.
WeekNumbers: 1 , 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7
WeekNumber Duplicates with same DayofWeek sequences: WeekNumber 5 is duplicate of WeekNumber 2 & WeekNumber 7 is a duplicate of WeekNumber 6.
Arrays identified:
1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6
Script output:
1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6.

@Blindspots in my answer below. I figured out how to include sorting the google sheet after the data has been copied over. But it changes the order of the staff members. Is there a way to keep the order of the staff members, but still be able to sort by WeekNumber within the staff members? Or is StaffUserID sort ascending, WeekNumber sort Ascending after data is copied over the only way?
Like it would be cool to "lock" the staff groups in place and sort the week numbers with their respective rows per group so the list doesn't change. What do you think?

Yes, simply add an index to the data as you start processing it then sort by that at the end and remove it. I've cleaned up my comments since you're sorted out now.  You may wish to do the same.

function removeDuplicateDaysAndWriteToNewSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var originalSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    var newSheetName = "NewSheet"; // Replace "NewSheet" with your target sheet name
    var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(newSheetName);
    
    // Check if newSheet exists, create it if not
    if (!newSheet) {
        newSheet = ss.insertSheet(newSheetName);
    }
    
    var data = originalSheet.getRange("A2:D" + originalSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Assuming data starts from A2

    // Add an index to each row
    data = data.map((row, index) => [index + 1].concat(row));

    // Collect unique keys in the order they are encountered
    var uniqueKeys = [];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        var key = row[1] + "_" + row[2];
        if (!uniqueKeys.includes(key)) {
            uniqueKeys.push(key);
        }
    });

    // Sort uniqueKeys based on the order they were encountered in the data
    uniqueKeys.sort(function(a, b) {
        var indexOfA = data.findIndex(function(row) {
            return (row[1] + "_" + row[2]) === a;
        });
        var indexOfB = data.findIndex(function(row) {
            return (row[1] + "_" + row[2]) === b;
        });
        return indexOfA - indexOfB;
    });

    var groupedData = {};
    var nonUniqueSequences = {}; // Store non-unique sequences

    // Group data by TaskID and StaffUserID
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        var index = row[0];
        var taskID = row[1];
        var staffUserID = row[2];
        var weekNumber = row[3];
        var dayOfWeek = row[4];
        
        var key = taskID + "_" + staffUserID;
        if (!groupedData[key]) {
            groupedData[key] = {};
            groupedData[key]['sequences'] = {};
            groupedData[key]['uniqueWeekNumbers'] = {}; // Store unique week numbers
            groupedData[key]['firstUniqueWeekNumber'] = 1; // Initialize first unique week number
            groupedData[key]['lastUniqueWeekNumber'] = null; // Initialize last unique week number
            groupedData[key]['nonUniqueCount'] = 0; // Initialize non-unique count
            groupedData[key]['maxWeekNumber'] = 0; // Initialize max week number
            groupedData[key]['countUniqueWeekNumber'] = 0; // Initialize max week number
        }
        
        if (!groupedData[key]['sequences'][weekNumber]) {
            groupedData[key]['sequences'][weekNumber] = [];
        }
        
        groupedData[key]['sequences'][weekNumber].push([index, dayOfWeek]);
        
        // Update max week number
        if (weekNumber > groupedData[key]['maxWeekNumber']) {
            groupedData[key]['maxWeekNumber'] = weekNumber;
        }
    });

    // Iterate through grouped data to identify non-unique sequences and calculate overall lastUniqueWeekNumber per StaffUserID
    for (var key in groupedData) {
        if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var taskID = key.split("_")[0];
            var staffUserID = key.split("_")[1];
            
            // Track unique sequences of DayOfWeek for each WeekNumber
            var uniqueSequences = {};
            var lastUniqueWeekNumber = null;
            
            for (var weekNumber in groupedData[key]['sequences']) {
                if (groupedData[key]['sequences'].hasOwnProperty(weekNumber)) {
                    var sequence = JSON.stringify(groupedData[key]['sequences'][weekNumber].map(item => item[1]));
                    if (!uniqueSequences[sequence]) {
                        uniqueSequences[sequence] = true;
                        lastUniqueWeekNumber = weekNumber;
                        // Store unique week numbers for this subgroup
                        groupedData[key]['uniqueWeekNumbers'][weekNumber] = true;
                    } else {
                        Logger.log("Non-unique Week Number: " + weekNumber + " in group: " + key + ", Last Unique Week Number: " + lastUniqueWeekNumber);
                        // Store non-unique sequences
                        if (!nonUniqueSequences[key]) {
                            nonUniqueSequences[key] = {};
                        }
                        if (!nonUniqueSequences[key][weekNumber]) {
                            nonUniqueSequences[key][weekNumber] = [];
                        }
                        nonUniqueSequences[key][weekNumber].push(groupedData[key]['sequences'][weekNumber]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Log lastUniqueWeekNumber for each group
            Logger.log("Last Unique WeekNumber for StaffUserID " + staffUserID + " is: " + lastUniqueWeekNumber);
            
            // Calculate last unique week number based on the maximum week number encountered
            groupedData[key]['lastUniqueWeekNumber'] = lastUniqueWeekNumber;
        }
    }

    // Calculate overall lastUniqueWeekNumber per StaffUserID
    var overallLastUniqueWeekNumbers = {}; // Store overall lastUniqueWeekNumber per StaffUserID
    for (var key in groupedData) {
        if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var staffUserID = key.split("_")[1];
            var lastUniqueWeekNumber = groupedData[key]['lastUniqueWeekNumber'];
            if (!overallLastUniqueWeekNumbers[staffUserID] || lastUniqueWeekNumber > overallLastUniqueWeekNumbers[staffUserID]) {
                overallLastUniqueWeekNumbers[staffUserID] = lastUniqueWeekNumber;
            }
        }
    }

    // Copy data to the new sheet including both unique and non-unique sequences using overall lastUniqueWeekNumber per StaffUserID
    for (var key in groupedData) {
        if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var taskID = key.split("_")[0];
            var staffUserID = key.split("_")[1];
            var lastUniqueWeekNumber = overallLastUniqueWeekNumbers[staffUserID];
            
            for (var weekNumber = 1; weekNumber <= lastUniqueWeekNumber; weekNumber++) {
                // Filter data to include only rows belonging to the current taskID and staffUserID group
                var filteredData = data.filter(function (row) {
                    return row[1] === taskID && row[2] === staffUserID && row[3] == weekNumber;
                });

                // Iterate over the filtered data and append rows to the new sheet
                filteredData.forEach(function (row) {
                    if (newSheet) { // Check if newSheet exists
                        if (groupedData[key]['uniqueWeekNumbers'][weekNumber]) {
                            // Copy if week number is unique
                            newSheet.appendRow(row);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Logger.log("Target sheet '" + newSheetName + "' not found."); // Log error if newSheet is null
                    }
                });

                // Copy non-unique sequences for the current weekNumber
                if (nonUniqueSequences[key] && nonUniqueSequences[key][weekNumber]) {
                    nonUniqueSequences[key][weekNumber].forEach(function(seq) {
                        seq.forEach(function(day) {
                            newSheet.appendRow([seq[0][0], taskID, staffUserID, weekNumber, day[1]]); // Copying index as well
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Sort the data on the new sheet by the index column (added as the first column)
    if (newSheet) {
        var lastRow = newSheet.getLastRow();
        var range = newSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 5); // Assuming there are now 5 columns including the index
        range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]); // Sort by the index column (column 1) in ascending order
    } else {
        Logger.log("Target sheet '" + newSheetName + "' not found."); // Log error if newSheet is null
    }
}



This finds the unique sequences and then copies all sequences per TaskID and StaffUserID group before the last unique sequence.
However, it is not formatting the output as needed. Currently debugging with logs.
For example: Needing all WeekNumbers for TaskID & StaffUserID before the last unique WeekNumber per group: TaskID&StaffUserID. WeekNumbers: 1 , 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7 WeekNumber Duplicates with same DayofWeek sequences: WeekNumber 5 is duplicate of WeekNumber 2 & WeekNumber 7 is a duplicate of WeekNumber 6. Arrays identified: 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6 Script output: 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6.

I figured out how to sort the data after the copied data is placed on the new sheet.
It would be nice to have the data sorted by the original placement though. In such that it keeps the staff groups where they are and sorts the WeekNumbers.. Instead of sorting the Staff groups ascending and then the WeekNumbers. Which changes the order of the Staff from the original data file.
